# How to shows grouped header list in windows phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

i need this type of page in my application is this possible to make this kind of selection list in windows phone. please help me and provide me the right direction to achieve this.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Silverlight, you need to use a `LongListSelector`, which already has support for sections (A-Z, or whatever you want).

You can follow Microsoft's tutorial here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj244365(v=vs.105).aspx

However, for the newer Windows Runtime, the class is now `ListView`. You can see how to use it here: http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2014/04/28/Migrating-from-the-LongListSelector-to-the-ListView-in-Windows-Phone-XAML-Apps.aspx

Please note that it will be visually different than iOS.

Comment: phone:LongListSelector is not supported in my application its giving me error when i am using this line of code............error-->------LongListSelector is not supported in a Windows Phone project------------.

Comment: Please Provide me demo code if it possible bcoz that link is not working in my app. still i'm getting error from that.........

Comment: @CISWP8.1Dev, I'm sorry, I haven't used the new class. You should be able to look for more tutorials online, or ask specific questions about what's not working, so that others can help you.

Comment: Thanks but i got idea from that....